# Searching saved data file within Java

Tags: java, search

I am making a Library System in Java, I am able to add new books, view and save them. However, I now want to search them using a Search window box. The saved data is located in a txt file. I would like to search for specific fields. I am thinking of implementing a linear search method, but am not too sure how to do it.

```
package bcu.storer;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import bcu.model.Book;


public class BookStorer {

public void StoreBooks(ArrayList<Book> booksList) throws IOException
{

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(".\\data\\books.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    try {

    for (int i = 0; i < booksList.size(); i++)
    {
        String content = "";
        Book book = booksList.get(i);
        content += book.getIsbn()+"::";
        content += book.getTitle()+"::";
        content += book.getAuthor()+"::";
        content += book.getPublisher()+"::";
        content += book.getPudDate()+"::";
        content += book.getStatus()+"\n";


        bw.write(content);
    }
    System.out.println("Complete storing all books!");

    } catch (IOException ae) {

        ae.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

          try {

              if (bw != null)
                   bw.close();

              if (fw != null)
                   fw.close();

          } catch (IOException ex) {

              ex.printStackTrace();
          }


    }
}
```

}

This is the code which stores the book information to the TXT file, I would like to access this data in the search results.

Comment: You have to keep reading each line, get the context, split by `::` and search if its that what you are looking for

Comment: You should really consider switching to using a database (either an embedded one, or using a database server). This will really simplify things like this after the initial extra complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This will read the file, line by line, and will get all the lines that match the search criteria.

This map provides the position (column) of each of the fields in the `Book` object.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> fieldToPositionMap = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()
                .put("Isbn", 0)
                .put("Title", 1)
                .put("Author", 2)
                .put("Publisher", 3)
                .put("PudDate", 4)
                .put("Status", 5)      
                .build();
```

*Note:* I have used GoogleGuava's [ImmutableMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) to construct the map, but you can build it in a traditional way.

The search method takes the name of the field and the value that you want to search for (eg, Isbn=ABC or Publisher=XYZ) and returns all the rows (as Book objects) that match the criteria.

```
public List<Book> search(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
    try {
        return Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/txt/file")) //reads a file line by line
                .filter(line -> {
                    String[] blocks = line.split("::");
                    //filter (choose) a row if value of the searched field equals the provided value
                    return blocks[fieldToPositionMap.get(fieldName)].equals(fieldValue);
                })
                .map(this::deserialize) //convert the line to a Book object
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collect the result
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
//To convert a row from the file to a Book instance
private Book deserialize(String line) {
    String [] blocks = line.split("::");
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setIsbn(blocks[0]);
    book.setTitle(blocks[1]);
    book.setAuthor(blocks[2]);
    book.setPublisher(blocks[3]);
    book.setPudDate(blocks[4]);
    book.setStaus(blocks[5]);
}
Note: You might have to handle cases when a row does not have all fields
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want. I help it helps you.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFromFile {

  private static final String FILENAME = "pathToFile";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;

    try {

        //br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
        fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Array[String] tmpBook = sCurrentLine.split("::");
            Book myBook = new Book(tmpBook(0),tmpBook(1),tmpBook(2), tmpBook(3), tmpBook(4), tmpBook(5))
            /*Check here if is the book you are looking for*/
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            if (br != null)
                br.close();

            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

}